# Trying graph a piecewise function with Python Sympy, but don't know why all y-values are squeezed into a line

Tags: python, plot, sympy

I am trying to graph the following piecewise function:

f(x)=1 for 4<x<6
f(x)=0 otherwise

The following is my code:

```
import sympy as sym
import sympy.plotting as sym_plot
sym.init_printing()
x= sym.symbols('x')
f_2 = sym.Piecewise((1, (4<x)),(1,(x<6)),(0,True))
sym_plot.plot(f_2, (x,-10,10))
```

My plot displays the following:
[image]

Could anyone give me some help. Thank you somuch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it has to do with the order in which you supply the conditionals. From sympy.Piecewise doc, "the conditions are evaluated in turn, **returning the first that is `True`**.:

```
 |    Piecewise( (expr,cond), (expr,cond), ... )
 |      - Each argument is a 2-tuple defining an expression and condition
 |      - The conds are evaluated in turn returning the first that is True.
 |        If any of the evaluated conds are not determined explicitly False,
 |        e.g. x < 1, the function is returned in symbolic form.
```

I find that reshaping the conds like this:

```
import sympy as sym
import sympy.plotting as sym_plot
sym.init_printing()
x= sym.symbols('x')
f_2 = sym.Piecewise((0, x<=4), (0, x >=6), (1, x<6), (1, x>4))
sym_plot.plot(f_2, (x,-10,10))
```

...gives me this:

[image]

Is this what you're after?

By the way - it's interesting to evaluate `f_2` by itself to see how it formulates itself based on the conditionals you give it. Your original code produced an `f_2` that evaluated to `1`. I tried to shape the conditionals a couple of different ways and evaluated `f_2` for each attempt until I got the following based on the formulation of `f_2` I've shown above:

```
⎧0  for x ≥ 6 ∨ x ≤ 4
⎨                    
⎩1      otherwise
```

So evaluating it like this gives you a useful way to check that `f_2` ends up meaning what you wanted it to mean.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is just a practice about Fourier series.